# Strange output array in Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, arrays, simple-html-dom

I have this code derived from [simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) (click tab scraping slashdot)

```
foreach($html->find('body') as $article) {
    $item[]     = $article->find('img', 1)->outertext;
    $item[]    = $article->find('img', 7)->outertext;
    $item[] = $article->find('img', 9)->outertext;
    $articles[] = $item;
}

print_r($articles);
```

It works giving me the images at the appropriate index but its also returning some strange plain text between the images like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMAGE  [1] => IMAGE [2] =>  IMAGE ) )
```

IMAGE is the actual image being outputted

So my question is; Why does it output like this? Is the array formatting wrong? What can I do to get rid of the plain text?

Comment: print_r displays the array variable object in a human readable form. (used for testing purposes like var_dump($array)) It doesn't convert the image in <img> tags to display the image content.

Comment: @KarelG I tried several things: echo, print in combination with ->outertext, nothing seems to work which is weird because it should..Thanks for pointing out the problem